# recursive power algorithm

Tags: code-golf, tips

Have a look at my (javascript) version of a O(log(n)) x<sup>n</sup> algorithm:

```
function pow(x,n)
{
     return n==0?1:n==1?x:n==2?x*x:pow(pow(x,(n-n%2)/2),2)*(n%2==0?1:x);
}
```

Can you get it shorter?

Comment: other languages, which does it shorter are also welcome!

Comment: Python, 4 chars: `x**n`

Comment: this dosn't count, cause it's not a algo itself. It use an underlying algorithm.

Comment: I think I win this one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind using a global variable:

```
return n?(t=pow(x,n>>1))*t*(n%2?x:1):1
```

Through some ingenious trickery, Howard devised a clean alternative:

```
return n?(n%2?x:1)*(x=pow(x,n>>1))*x:1
```

And Peter Taylor managed to shave one character:

```
return(n%2?x:1)*(x=n?pow(x,n>>1):1)*x
```

Even shorter based on ratchet freak's idea:

```
return(n%2?x:1)*(n?pow(x*x,n>>1):1)
```

Comment: nice, but it's not a real recursion cause of the glob. var..  but never mind its not bad!

Comment: @ChrisTobba Well, it is recursive, the variable doesn't have to be global as the value is only used in the same invocation. It's just shorter to make it (implicitly) global. You could add "var t" before the return to make it local.

Comment: Or if you don't want to use a global variable: `return n?(n%2?x:1)*(x=pow(x,n>>1))*x:1`

Comment: nice... good programmers out there!

Comment: may I ask how old you are(to code so beautiful)? I'm 28

Comment: I'm 0b100010 :)

Comment: Or for one character less and a different perspective on the structure, `return(n%2?x:1)*(x=n?pow(x,n>>1):1)*x`

Comment: @peter nice! i love recursive algo`s.. so much logic in such a short form..

Comment: @PeterTaylor don't you think you should post that as an answer?

Comment: I'm not sure from memory whether it's been discussed on meta, but the general etiquette seems to be that for very small improvements by refactoring someone else's code we post a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Ok I don't know much about etiquette, I credited you in my answer

Comment: What am I missing here, why can you not just use the far more simple, literal `return n?pow(x,n-1)*x:1`. Is that `pow` function doing something more that I don't understand?

Comment: hmmm... starting to notice difference when not using positive integers... what is that `pow` function doing exactly?

Comment: @BillyMoon n is assumed to be a non-negative integer, and your implementation runs in O(n) instead of O(log n) - compare pow(1, 1000000000). If you don't understand how it works, the basic idea is: x^(2*k)=(x^k)^2 and x^(2*k+1)=x*(x^k)^2 (^ = power in this context)

Answer (score 4):

BrainFuck (482 characters)

Solution is modulo 256. Reads n in digit by digit.  Each time it sees a new digit d, it raises the current value to the tenth power and then multiplies that by x^d
Input must be x followed by single space, followed by n, followed by newline

```
>,--------------------------------[--------------->,--------------------------------]<[<]>>[<-[->++++++++++<]>>]<->+>>>>>,----------[--------------------------------------<++++++++++<+>[-<[-<<<[->+>+<<]>[-<+>]>>]<[->+<]>>]<[-<+>]>>[-<<+>>]<<<<<[-]>>>[-<[-<<<[->+>+<<]>[-<+>]>>]<[->+<]>>]<[-<<+>>]>>>,----------]>>+<<+<<+<<+<<[-]>[->[>+----------[>-<[-<+>]]<-[->+<]+>++++++++++>]+<<[<----------<]>++++++++++]>[>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>]<<<<[>.<<<]++++++++++.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function pow(x,n)
{
     return n==0?1:n==1?x:pow(x*x,n>>1)*pow(x,n&1);
}
```

removed the `n==2` case,

replaced the `(n-n%2)/2` with `n>>1` (you can also use `n&-2`)

used `x*x` instead of `pow(pow(...),2)`

replaced `*(n%2==0?1:x)` with `*pow(x,n&1)`

Answer (score 2):

### GolfScript (29 chars as function, 24 chars as block)

```
{1@@2base-1%{{.@*\}*.*}/;}:P;
```

without the function wrapper that's

```
1@@2base-1%{{.@*\}*.*}/;
```

It's not recursive, but it is `O(lg n)` time, using the binary decomposition of `n`. Essentially it takes the fact that the recursive `pow` can be made tail-recursive with an accumulator and pushes that to its conclusion:

```
# Stack: a n
1@@
# Stack: 1 a n
2base
# Stack: 1 a [bits of n]
# Reverse the bits so that we loop over them starting at the least significant
-1%
# foreach
{
    # Stack: accum x bit
    # where accum = a^(n%(2^i)) and x = a^(2^i)

    # If the bit is set, multiply the accumulator by x
    {.@*\}*

    # Square x
    .*
}/
# Pop the unwanted a^(2^(2+lg n)) and we're left with a^n
;
```

(There is also the built-in `?` for one char, but I don't think that's in the spirit of this codegolf).

Comment: Love the :P at the end of the first one!

Answer (score 0):

## GolfScript - 33

This feels awfully clumsy but here it goes:

```
{.2/.{2$\P}{;1}if.*@@1&{*.}*;}:P;
```

Usage: `2 11P` -> `2048`

(Thanks Peter Taylor)

Comment: Simple `if`s can often be replaced by `bool{...}*`. In the case of `\1&{*}{\;}if` (12 ch) observe that the `*` doesn't care about the order of its arguments, so could be `\1&{\*}{\;}if` (13 ch); now reorder things so that the common `\ ` is unnecessary: a bit of work shows that `@@1&{*}{;}if` (12 ch) is equivalent. But now the else clause does virtually nothing; refactor via `@@1&{*.}{}if;` (13 ch) to `@@1&{*.}*;` (10 ch). I haven't checked whether a similar elimination can be performed on the first `if`.

Comment: its unreadable for me.. but also nice! On golfscript.com i doesn't found an interpreter for that.. Is it only a pseudo code language?

Comment: @ChrisTobba, the interpreter is at http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/golfscript.rb (and requires Ruby). See also http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/521/194

Answer (score 0):

### Java

```
int pow(int x, int n){
    int t=1;
    return n==0?1:(n%2==0?1:x)*(t=pow(x,n/2))*t;
}
```

And if `t` is an initialized class variable, you can remove the first line.

Answer (score 0):

**C++, 44 characters**

```
int p(int x,int n){return !n?1:x*p(x,n-1);}
```

Comment: This runs in O(n) time.

Answer (score 0):

### k4 (38)

fairly straightforward port of the java solution

`{$[y;*/((y-2*r)#x),2#x .z.s/r:_y%2;1]}`

Answer (score 0):

#### Haskell, 49 characters

```
x^0=1;x^2=x*x;x^n|odd n=x*x^(n-1)|1>0=x^div n 2^2
```

readable version:

```
x^0 = 1
x^2 = x * x
x^n | odd  x = x * x^(n-1)
    | even x = x ^ (d`div`2) ^ 2
```

The idea to special-case x^2 shamelessly stolen from the asker.

Another 49-character version, requires common subexpression elimination (which GHCi doesn't do in this case) to be efficient:

```
x^0=1;x^n|odd n=x*x^(n-1)|1>0=x^div n 2*x^div n 2
```

Answer (score -1):

In python we have 2 methods for doing this :

```
def p(x,n,l):
    print pow(x,n,l)
def p1(x,n):
    print x**n
p(10,5,52)
p1(10,5)
```

Output corresponding to it is:

```
4
100000
```

The best part in python function is that it helps in modular power also (which is faster than finding power and then mod).In pow (n,m,l) It produces : (n^m)%l as the  output.

Comment: You have not written an algorithm as the question asks, you're using Python's builtin algorithms. In JS it can be done with `Math.pow()`, so this is in no way interesting...

Answer (score -1):

### PHP

```
function p($x,$n){return($n>1)?p($x*$x,$n-1):$x}
```

Comment: This doesn't compute powers (it instead computes `x^(2^(n-1))` ) and isn't logarithmic time in `n`